# Can I get my pictures back?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

Okay so I recently jail broke my phone and well my phone broke it doesn't work no more like at all, it doesn't even turn on. And well the only way to fix it is to unjailbreak it and to do that I need to restore it I tried doing that with iTunes and it does let me but what it does not let me do is back up my device and if I restore it everything is going to erase. Is there a way to get everything back specially my pictures after I restore my phone?

Answer (score 4):

If the device isn't backed up previously, short answer: No.

I haven't used any data recovery apps for iPhones before, but a quick google will help you find a few commercial apps that might help you. But the chance that it will succeed after erasing and installing a new working OS will be limited.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting your device to your computer and viewing the files through a program like iexplorer? You might be able to access your photos this way? If your phone isn't turning on however this could still not work.